# HTML::Template::Pro: do something on second run of a loop

Tags: perl, loops, if-statement, perl-html-template

I am using HTML::Template::Pro in my perl application. I am displaying HTML elements in a loop and I want to show something after the second element of the loop. I added the `loop_context_vars` in my HTML::Template::Pro initialization, getting access to variables inside the loop (like `__counter__`).

Now I am looking for a way to check for a specific iteration of this loop to insert my HTML element.

```
<TMPL_IF __counter__ == 2>
   My new HTML element.
</TMPL_IF>
```

How can I access the `__counter__` variable inside conditional statements in HTML::Template::Pro?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML::Template::Pro, you can use expressions like in HTML::Template::Expr

```
<TMPL_IF EXPR="__counter__ == 2" >
    My new HTML element.
</TMPL_IF>
```